# PDF reader that allows user to alternate between reading on PC and on Mac

Tags: pdf, windows, mac-os

I have to read a lot of eBooks (PDF) and am wondering whether there is an app out there that allows me to alternate between reading on Windows PC and on Macbook Air. I am thinking about an app that syncs all the notes and markups between devices and opens with the last page I read. C

Comment: [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) Calibre is one of best e-book reader and converter, I'm using it in Linux, it's available for OSX and Win http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39501/how-to-access-your-ebook-collection-anywhere-in-the-world/
I have not ever synchronized ebook between devices